# Using exclusive + durable queues, for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

If I have made a queue which is exclusive and durable (not auto-delete). Now, if the consumer subscribes to that queue and then it goes down. Then that queue gets deleted.

I have checked the scenario, when the queue is only durable (i.e. neither exclusive nor auto-delete). Now, if the consumer subscribes to that queue and then it goes down. Then that queue gets deleted.

Please explain the 1st case, 2nd case is giving expected result. In both the scenario only 1 consumer is subscribed to one queue, and there is only one queue bound to one direct_exchange.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a queue that is exclusive, then when the channel that declared the queue is closed, the queue is deleted.

If you have a queue that is auto-deleted, then when there are no subscriptions left on that queue it will be deleted.

These two rules apply even for durable queues.

Comment: Why would they do that? I really like the exclusiveness feature (lock) but can't afford to loose messages in the queue when the service processing the messages goes down. I can only have one service running processing messages and when it goes down, the fail back service will detect that it can now have exclusive rights to the queue and take ownership. But if the messages are gone! It's rather useless to me.

Comment: Answering this question from ancient times since it took me a while to find out the answer to it: What you actually want is exclusive consume, not exclusive queue.

Comment: Not exactly. Not the channel should be closed to allow removal of exclusive queue, but Connection. Here is the official documentation : https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#queues

Answer (score 7):

One thing to correct, the exclusive queue will be deleted after the **connection** is closed not the channel is closed. you can run this test:

```java
package rabbitmq.java.sample.exclusivequeue;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk;

public class Producer {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "UserLogin2";
    private final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "user.login";
    
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionFactory factory=new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("CNCDS108");
        try {
            Connection conn = factory.newConnection();          
            Channel channel =conn.createChannel();
            DeclareOk declareOk = channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, true, false, null);
                
            channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, "Hello".getBytes());
            
            //close the channel, check if the queue is deleted
            System.out.println("Try to close channel");
            channel.close();
            System.out.println("Channel closed");
            
            System.out.println("Create a new channel");
            Channel channel2 =conn.createChannel();
            DeclareOk declareOk2 = channel2.queueDeclarePassive(QUEUE_NAME);
            
            **//we can access the exclusive queue from another channel
            System.out.println(declareOk2.getQueue()); //will output "UserLogin2"
            channel2.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, "Hello2".getBytes());
            System.out.println("Message published through the new channel");**
            
//          System.out.println("Try to close Connection");
//          conn.close();
//          System.out.println("Connection closed");
            
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```